# Search for multiple values, if found, check offset contains a value, highlight offset cell if it has no value

Tags: excel

On an Excel spreadsheed I need to check the values in columns 10, 12 and 14 from row 2 down to avoid the header row.  I am looking for Planet Names: Mercury, Mars, Jupiter, Neptune and Saturn.  The number of rows will vary so I am hoping someone can assist with a VBA solution.

If any of the planets are found in these columns then a check needs to take place on Column 20 to see if it contains a value in the same row.  If it does not have a value, then the cell in Column 20 needs to be coloured red.

Examples

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10.  Column 20, cell T10 has a value so cell T10 is not coloured red

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10.  Column 20, cell T10 has No value so cell T10 is coloured red

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10, has Saturn in L10, Column 20, cell T10 has a value so cell T10 is not coloured red

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10, has Saturn in L10, Column 20, cell T10 has No value so cell T10 is coloured red

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10, has Saturn in L10, has Jupiter in N10, Column 20, cell T10 has a value so cell T10 is Not coloured red

Column 10 has Mars in cell J10, has Saturn in L10, has Jupiter in N10, Column 20, cell T10 has No value so cell T10 is coloured red

Any assistance in a VBA solution would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can be achieve using conditional formatting, as in this screenshot:
More information about this feature can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

[image: Screenshot]